# How to average of last days data in influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I want to calculate the average of unit_price from entries of the last known day from my influxdb database.

Below shows you the last two days data I have (14 entries per day)
I have 5 different days data in total.

```
> select * from "variable" order by time desc limit 28
name: variable
time                 area_code area_name                     unit_price
----                 --------- ---------                     ----------
2021-05-11T23:00:00Z P         Northern_Scotland             18.4695
2021-05-11T23:00:00Z N         Southern_Scotland             17.598
2021-05-11T23:00:00Z M         Yorkshire                     16.968
2021-05-11T23:00:00Z L         South_Western_England         18.6795
2021-05-11T23:00:00Z K         Southern_Wales                18.081
2021-05-11T23:00:00Z J         South_Eastern_England         18.501
2021-05-11T23:00:00Z H         Southern_England              17.5875
2021-05-11T23:00:00Z G         North_Western_England         17.4615
2021-05-11T23:00:00Z F         North_Eastern_England         17.262
2021-05-11T23:00:00Z E         West_Midlands                 17.6085
2021-05-11T23:00:00Z D         Merseyside_and_Northern_Wales 19.4355
2021-05-11T23:00:00Z C         London                        17.4405
2021-05-11T23:00:00Z B         East_Midlands                 17.3565
2021-05-11T23:00:00Z A         Eastern_England               17.871
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z P         Northern_Scotland             17.073
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z N         Southern_Scotland             16.2225
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z M         Yorkshire                     15.6135
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z L         South_Western_England         17.094
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z K         Southern_Wales                16.527
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z J         South_Eastern_England         16.8945
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z H         Southern_England              16.128
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z G         North_Western_England         16.0125
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z F         North_Eastern_England         15.7395
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z E         West_Midlands                 16.086
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z D         Merseyside_and_Northern_Wales 17.8605
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z C         London                        15.897
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z B         East_Midlands                 15.8445
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z A         Eastern_England               16.2855
```

As you can see here, limit 14 average shows the same result as not using limit at all.
So this mean command is averaging 'all' the data, not any limited data.

```
select mean(unit_price) from "variable" order by time desc limit 14
name: variable
time                 mean
----                 ----
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 16.2924375

> select mean(unit_price) from "variable"
name: variable
time                 mean
----                 ----
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 16.2924375
>
```

I have tried nested selects, but can’t seem to find how to get an average of the final 14 entries (or from the final date with data)

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Think I may have solved with after playing some more with nested queries.

```
> select mean(unit_price) from "variable" group by time(1d) fill(none)
name: variable
time                 mean
----                 ----
2019-04-12T00:00:00Z 15.572249999999997
2020-01-15T00:00:00Z 15.340499999999997
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z 16.377
2021-05-11T00:00:00Z 17.880000000000003

> select last("mean") from (select mean(unit_price) from "variable" group by time(1d) fill(none))
name: variable
time                 last
----                 ----
2021-05-11T00:00:00Z 17.880000000000003
>
```